# Galaxy Note 2 synonym requests

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

A couple of tags have cropped up which should be synonyms of [samsung-galaxy-note-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-2):

- [noteii](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noteii)
- [galaxy-note-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-note-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Thanks for catching those.